# Remove punctuation in Python but keep emoticons

Tags: python, sentiment-analysis

I'm doing research on sentiment analysis. In a list of data, I'd like to remove all punctuation, in orde to get to the words in their pure version.  But I would like to keep emoticons, such as :) and :/.

Is there a way to say in Python that I want to remove all punctuation signs unless they appear in a combination such as ":)", ":/", "<3"?

Thanks in advance

This is my code for the stripping:

```
for message in messages:
message=message.lower()
message=message.replace("!","")
message=message.replace(".","")
message=message.replace(",","")
message=message.replace(";","")
message=message.replace(";","")
message=message.replace("?","")

message=message.replace("/","")
message=message.replace("#","")
```

Comment: Sounds like you want to do string manipulation? There are various ways of doing this, from `str.replace` to `regex`. What have you tried so far? Here are some helpful links:

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_replace.htm

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_reg_expressions.htm

Comment: I did it with str.replace. I edited my original post to show my code.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this regex:

```
(?<=\w)[^\s\w](?![^\s\w])
```

Usage:

```
import re
print(re.sub(r'(?<=\w)[^\s\w](?![^\s\w])', '', your_data))
```

---

[Here](https://regex101.com/r/Z5oLPh/1) is an online demo.

The idea is to match a single special character if it is preceded by a letter.

If the regex doesn't work as you expect, you can customize it a little. For example if you don't want it to match commas, you can remove them from the character class like so: `(?<=\w)[^\s\w,](?![^\s\w])`. Or if you want to remove the emoticon `:-)`, you can add it to the regex like so: `(?<=\w)[^\s\w](?![^\s\w])|:-\)`.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet might be to simply declare a list of emoticons as a variable. Then compare your punctuation to the list. If it's not in the list, remove it from the string.

Edit: Instead of using a whole block of str.replace() over and over, you might try something like:

```
to_remove = ".,;:!()\"
for char in to_remove:
    message = message.replace(char, "")
```

Edit 2:

The simplest way (skill-wise) might be to try this:

```
from string import punctuation
emoticons = [":)" ":D" ":("]
word_list = message.split(" ")
for word in word_list:
    if word not in emoticons:
        word = word.translate(None, punctuation)
output = " ".join(word_list)
```

Once again, this will only work on emoticons that are separated from other characters, i.e. `"Sure :D"` but not `"Sorry:("`.

Comment: Could you perhaps elaborate on how I do this concretely?

Comment: Well, you could try doing this a few different ways. The simplest one I can think of (in terms of skill) would be to try using `message.split(" ")` to separate your message into words. `"Hello, friend :)"` will end up as `["Hello,", "friend", ":)"]`. Then iterate through the list, comparing each word to the list of emoticons you're looking for. If it's not on the list, strip all punctuation using `word.replace()`. Keep in mind this will only work on emoticons that are separated, i.e. will work on `"Hi :)"`, but not on `"Hello:D"`.

Comment: I did the first steps (the splitting), but I don't understand how I should write the for loop?

Comment: I added a simple code to my post, so it's better visible than in the comments. Let me know what you think.

Answer (score 0):

Going off of the work you've already done using `str.replace`, you could do something like this:

```
lines = [
    "Sentence 1.",
    "Sentence 2 :)",
    "Sentence <3 ?"
]

emoticons = {
    ":)": "000smile",
    "<3": "000heart"
}

emoticons_inverse = {v: k for k, v in emoticons.items()}

punctuation = ",./<>?;':\"[]\\{}|`~!@#$%^&*()_+-="

lines_clean = []
for line in lines:
    #Replace emoticons with non-punctuation
    for emote, rpl in emoticons.items():
        line = line.replace(emote, rpl)

    #Remove punctuation
    for char in line:
        if char in punctuation:
            line = line.replace(char, "")

    #Revert emoticons
    for emote, rpl in emoticons_inverse.items():
        line = line.replace(emote, rpl)

    lines_clean.append(line)

print(lines_clean)
```

This is not super efficient, though, so if performance becomes a bottleneck you might want to examine how you can make this faster.

Output: `python3 test.py`

```
['Sentence 1', 'Sentence 2 :)', 'Sentence <3 ']
```